# Split data and put it back together

Tags: c#, split, byte

This is more for practice than anything, really. I am having the most frustrating time with this as it's a fairly new concept to me. I will post my code below.

What I am attempting to do:

1. Read a file into a byte array
2. Split the byte into pars of a predefined size
3. Put the parts back together, and write the file to HD

   byte[] sData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Project1.exe");   // 16,384 bytes

   ```
   // Split the data up here
                   int range = 8;
                   range *= 1024;
                   int pos = 0;
                   int remaining;
                   int i = 0;
                   byte[] test = null;
                   while ((remaining = sData.Length - pos) > 0)
                   {
                       byte[] block = new byte[Math.Min(remaining, range)];
                       test = new byte[block.Length + pos];
                       Array.Copy(sData, pos, test, pos, block.Length);
                       pos += block.Length;
                       i++;
                   }

                   File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\blank.exe", test);
   ```

The file "blank.exe" is always corrupt.

Does anyone see my error(s) here?

I appreciate it, Evan

Comment: It's better to leave your question up so the next person who googles for the same problem doesn't have to ask.

Comment: Where is your original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating the test array on each pass through the loop.

This means when you write the test array to the file at the end, you are only writing the last block of data that you processed.

You have a few options:

1) Resize the array on each pass and copy the previous data into the new array. This would be very inefficient. This is the same mechanism that Array.Resize uses.

2) If you know the desired size of the array ahead of time (i.e. it is the same size as the data you read from the file or a multiple of the file size), then just resize the array one time before entering the loop.

3) Use a different data structure, such as as List or an ArrayList.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand the problem - but how can I re-size the array to fit all of the data then? OR, do I need to know the size of the array in advance?

Comment: I'll let someone else answer your question directly because, well, I don't know the answer off the top of my head.  However, if you can find out what the entire size will be upfront that would keep you from having to adjust the size.

Comment: Figured it out - Array.Resize

Comment: I updated my answer: I was not aware of Array.Resize, but it will have a nasty performance impact. From the MSDN docs: If newSize is greater than the Length of the old array, a new array is allocated and all the elements are copied from the old array to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Like competent_tech said, you don't want to recreate the test array each time.

I'm not totally sure about this, but why not initialize `byte[] test = null;` to `byte[] test = sData.Length;` and remove `test = new byte[block.Length + pos];` from the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you're slurping in the entire file up front, so you already not how big the output buffer needs to be. Ergo, this should do you just fine:

```
private static void better_copy( ushort blockSize )
{
  if ( blockSize < 1 )  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("blockSize") ;

  byte[] input  = File.ReadAllBytes( @"C:\Project1.exe" );   // 16,384 bytes
  byte[] output = new byte[ input.Length] ;

  for ( int p = 0 , n = 0 ; p < input.Length ; p += n )
  {
    int octetsRemaining = input.Length - p ;

    n = ( octetsRemaining < blockSize ? octetsRemaining : blockSize ) ;

    Array.Copy( input , p , output , p , n ) ;

  }

  File.WriteAllBytes( @"C:\blank.exe" , output );

  return ;
}
```