# How to put it back the stored data into exact label in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I see the exactly the same questions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191013/split-data-and-put-it-back-together) but I want to know the code in vb (window form).
I have store the variable in

> Dim Lastname, Surname, Middlename, age As String

and the data are saved in notepad. how can I put them back in their exact label.
one of my lable is

> lbl_surname.Text

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that this below code helped me,

> Dim TextLine As String

```
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(openfile)
    Dim aryTextFile() As String  'this sets up an array to store the seperate parts of the line
    ' round brackets are blank because we don’t know how many we need (separate items) there are on each line
    If System.IO.File.Exists(openfile) = True Then 'see if file exists

        While objReader.Peek() <> -1  'takes a peek to find end of file, rteturns -1 if no more lines
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine() 'Read line
            lbl_data.Text = lbl_data.Text & vbNewLine & TextLine
            'Extracting required data fr
            aryTextFile = TextLine.Split(",") 'Inside the round brackets is symbol is used to separate each element in the line, in this case a comma.

            ' For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile) 'UBound means upper boundary of array, ie max number of variables
            'MsgBox(aryTextFile(i))
            ' Next i
            ' Put required bits from line in appropriate places on form

            Surname = aryTextFile(0) 'first part needed
            age = aryTextFile(3) 'second part needed
            Middlename = aryTextFile(1)
            Lastname = aryTextFile(2)
            mobile = aryTextFile(4)
            lbl_surname.Text = Surname 'Storing data into label for display
            lbl_lastname.Text = Lastname
            lbl_middlename.Text = Middlename
            lbl_age.Text = age 'Storing data into label for display
            lbl_mob.Text = mobile

        End While

    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it will help to someone who need it!